# thread safety question

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, thread-safety

I know we need to take care of thread safety for static member variables inside the class. Do we need to worry about the instance member variables?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on whether you want your type to be thread-safe... and what you mean by that.

Most of the time I think it's entirely reasonable to document that the type *isn't* thread-safe, but can be used safely from different threads with appropriate synchronization. Most .NET types fall into this category.

That would you can usually make sure that only "coordinating" objects need to worry about synchronization, rather than putting a lock in every method and property - a strategy which is painful, and doesn't really address the wider synchronization issues you're likely to run into anyway.

Of course, types which will *naturally* be used from multiple threads - ones specifically design to enable concurrency, or service locators etc, should be thread-safe - and be documented so. Likewise fully immutable types are naturally thread-safe to start with.

Finally, there's the matter of what counts as "thread-safe" to start with. You should read [Eric Lippert's blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/10/19/what-is-this-thing-you-call-thread-safe.aspx) on the matter to clarify what sort of thing you should be thinking about and documenting.

Comment: +1 For detailing that you can make the choice and document that a type is not thread-safe. Often when types are used together, it is not enough that a single type is thread-safe, as operations which span access to multiple types need to be synchronized. This is where you need your coordinating type to handle thread-safety across all the participating types.

Comment: @chibacity: Exactly. You can spend a lot of time and energy getting the *appearance* of safety, without actually getting any benefit (and ending up with a codebase which is harder to reason about).

Answer (score 4):

Yes you should care because the same class instance method could be passed as callback to multiple threads. Example:

```
var instance = new Foo();
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(instance.SomeInstanceMethod);
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(instance.SomeInstanceMethod);
```

The instance method now needs to be synchronized because in this case the shared state is the instance itself.

Comment: Are method names supposed to begin with capital letters in C#?

Comment: Good to know. Thanks.  I didn't see the C# tag at first and was thinking Java naming conventions.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following code:

```
public void Execute()
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(Iterrate);
    Task.Factory.StartNew(Add);
}

private List<int> _list = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).ToList();

private void Iterrate()
{
    foreach (var item in _list)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
}

private void Add()
{
    _list.Add(_list.Count);
}
```

This code will result (most of the times):

```
InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.
```

Comment: Nice code example, a little more explanation for posterity would be good ;) Not everyone is aware of the issues in this classic multi-threading problem scenario.

Comment: @chibacity: I believe that code snippet is worth a thousand words. Furthermore, I didn't find the time for extra info :)

Comment: Agreed - I understand the code all too well, but not everyone realizes the implications - that is what the original question is about after all. I made the comment as I would have liked to have up-voted your answer.